# PHP-Working with json

Tags: php

Iam working with json

My application get string that encoded by json_encode().

Example : The string like this {"data":"1", "data":"2", "data":"3"}

My app work well,

But if browser give me something before i get my string like this:  skdjksdjksdj{"data":"1", "data":"2", "data":"3"}

My app will get all skdjksdjksdj{"data":"1", "data":"2", "data":"3"} and don't work

How i can take only {"data":"1", "data":"2", "data":"3"} without "skdjksdjksdj" ?

i don't want to use str_replace , i don't want to output something to browser before output string that was encode by json , and maybe aslo after that

sorry for my bad english

P/S:

Exampele: i addtion something like "bla bla bla" before json data

```
bla bla bla bla bla
myDataJson
bla bla bla bla bla
```

my app will get above content to paser , but catch error with "bla bla bla "

How to filter to get only myDataJson

Comment: *Why* is the browser giving you something before the JSON data? What does the data look like exactly, can you make an example? Are you getting a [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) result?

Comment: Do you have the string "skdjksdjksdj" or "ksdj" anywhere in the script(s) executed to make the JSON output? Looks like "blahblah" someone put in there to prove execution during debugging.

Comment: i use joomla cms. If joomla output something before my json data , my app will not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe that only solutions here works this way - DO NOT OUTPUT ANYTHING BUT YOUR JSON STRING!
You are the one who makes your app to output like anything. So you have to deal with this :)

Comment: i use joomla cms. If joomla output something before my json data , my app will not work. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can strip the jSON before you do the json_decode() for example...

```
$json = "skdjksdjksdj{"data":"1", "data":"2", "data":"3"}"
```

strip the "skdjksdjksdj" how ever you like maybe like this...

Use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find where the **{"** is then do a [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) from that pos to the end of the string something like

```
substr(strpos("**{"**"), $json.length);
```

then you can go and so whatever e.g

```
json_decode($json, 1)
```

ect

good luck!